# How can I `print` or `cat` when using parallel

Tags: r, io, parallel-processing

If I call a function using `parSapply` then `print`, `message` or `cat` statements inside that function don't seem to output to the console.

My process takes a very long time, so I need some way of seeing the progress and getting the results output as they are done.  Are there any special commands that would allow me to print to the console from a parallel process?

Example:

```
library(parallel)

oneloop = function(x) {
  for(i in 1:50) {
    a = rnorm(100000)
    a = sort(a)
  }
  print(x)
  message(x)
  cat(x)
}

cl <- makeCluster(5)
output = parSapply(cl, 1:10, oneloop)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Thanks, have amended to include this

Comment: does `flush.console` have an effect?

Comment: @TylerRinker, nice idea, but nope, makes no difference.  I think the outputs for the worker processes must not be captured... ...so the question might be "can you redirect worker stdout to the main stdout", but I'm speculating now.

Comment: Closely related Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10903787/1036500

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Using `outfile` param in `makeCluster` you can redirect the output to a file and then check that file to see how your program progresses.

Interestingly on a Linux machine setting it to `""` outputs to the console, but that doesn't work for me on a Windows machine. File output works on both.

Comment: A slightly different approach to getting a progress log file when using `%dopar%` is documented in detail here: http://viksalgorithms.blogspot.com/2012/02/monitoring-progress-inside-foreach-loop.html

Comment: `outfile=""` doesn't work on Windows with Rgui, but it does with Rterm.

Comment: It's strange how poorly-documented this is. I had to pore through source code for a good 15 minutes before I found exactly what `outfile` is doing (basically being added to a command being sent to terminal as `OUT=` `outfile`). Sending to terminal with `""` is consistent with, e.g., `write.table`, which takes the connection `""` to mean `stdout`

Comment: Using the setting `outfile = ""` to print to the terminal works for me using emacs and ESS in Windows.

Answer (score 4):

I am using `makeCluster` with `outfile` on Windows with doParallel package version 1.0.8. I'm able to tail `outfile` using a simple Powershell command `powershell Get-Content c:/path/to/log/mylog.txt -wait`. Works for me.