# Capturing output from new threads in R

Tags: r, multithreading, parallel-processing, output, snow

I am running a multithreaded R script but I am having trouble with generating output from the cluster.

```
outFun <- function()
{
  cat(sample(0:9,1));
}
require(snow)
clust <- makeCluster(4)
clusterExport(clust,"outFun")
clustFun <- function(i){outFun()}
clusterApplyLB(clust,1:8,clustFun)
```

I understand that I don't see any of the output from `outFun()` because it's in a new R thread, but I was hoping that there would be some way to forward this output back to the master thread so it was visible when printed.

EDIT: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717461/how-can-i-print-or-cat-when-using-parallel) answers this for a Linux machine, but the solution does not work for Windows. The workaround given is to simply use file output, but I am curious if anyone knows a solution to be able to actually send output back to the master thread in Windows.

Comment: R is not multi-threaded.

Comment: @DWin as I have demonstrated in my code above, there are packages to make it multi-threaded...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `makeCluster` `outfile=""` option doesn't work with Rgui on Windows because Rgui doesn't send output from child processes to the display window.  However, `outfile=""` does work with the Rterm program because it's a simple console program:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\i386> rterm -q
> library(parallel)
> clust <- makeCluster(4, outfile="")
starting worker pid=1596 on localhost:11862 at 09:13:30.005
starting worker pid=1192 on localhost:11862 at 09:13:30.342
starting worker pid=1616 on localhost:11862 at 09:13:30.679
```

The "starting worker" messages are coming from the worker processes just before they execute the `slaveLoop` function.  You should also see output from the workers from executing tasks:

```
> clusterEvalQ(clust, message("hello"))
hello
hello
hello
hello
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL
```

Comment: Interesting solution, would not have thought the problem lied in the IDE.