# Parallel R : Output console messages from a child sourced script with parallel

Tags: r, shiny, parallel-processing, ipc, shiny-server

I'm struggling with a parallel R computation (on an Ubuntu 16.04 server, R version 3.6). I'm trying to

1) **source an external script** as a child process (with **mcparallel**)

2) and **display the output from the console** on the frontend of my app with ShinyJS.

Unfortunately, if the process works as planned, **nothing is output in the console (stderr or stdout)**, even with the argument "silent = FALSE".

**My first question** : Is there a way to force it with mcparallel ?

*Alternative* : How could it be achieved alternaltively with MakeCluster ? I read that the argument outfile = "" is meant to send output to the console. (ref : [How can I `print` or `cat` when using parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717461/how-can-i-print-or-cat-when-using-parallel))

**My second question** : How would you advise to send said console output to the Shiny front end with Shinyjs ? I know it should be done on the synchronous Shiny side but i'm open to ideas to make it effective.

My code :

```
library(parallel)
library(tools)

# Child process

wrapper <- function(){ source("external-script.R", local = TRUE, echo = TRUE) }
Job1 <- mcparallel(wrapper())
result <- mccollect(Job1, wait = FALSE)

# Script works as planned but no output on the console

# After a while Kill it

Sys.sleep(60)
    pskill(Job1$pid)
```

Comment: Child processes don't send their stder or stdout stream to the main process. Your script needs to return a value that goes into `result`. Printing (or `cat`ing) should happen in the main process.

Comment: Hello Roland and thank you for your answer. So is there no any other solution to send stder to the main process ?  Maybe with the processx library ?

Comment: I don't know but I strongly suggest that you don't follow that path and instead spend your time fixing the script.