# foreach gives the expected output only if I put a print statement at the end of the loop

Tags: r, for-loop, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I am using `foreach` to parallelize my code. However, I found the result to be different whether I add `print` statement at the end of the loop or not.

Here is with the `print` statement a the end (I get the result I want):

```
library(foreach)

grid <- expand.grid(
  lambda=c(1,2),
  mtry=c(1),
  nodsize=c(1)
)

n.cores <- parallel::detectCores() - 1
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/16718078/1979665
my.cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(n.cores, outfile = "")
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl = my.cluster)
params.all <- foreach (i = 1:nrow(grid), .combine = "rbind") %dopar% {
  params <- grid[i,]
  params$rmse <- "foo"
  print(params)
}
parallel::stopCluster(cl = my.cluster)
params.all
```

Result is:

```
  lambda mtry nodsize rmse
1      1    1       1  foo
2      2    1       1  foo
```

Here is without the `print` statement at the end:

```
library(foreach)

grid <- expand.grid(
  lambda=c(1,2),
  mtry=c(1),
  nodsize=c(1)
)

n.cores <- parallel::detectCores() - 1
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/16718078/1979665
my.cluster <- parallel::makeCluster(n.cores, outfile = "")
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl = my.cluster)
params.all <- foreach (i = 1:nrow(grid), .combine = "rbind") %dopar% {
  params <- grid[i,]
  params$rmse <- "foo"
  # print(params) LINE COMMENTED
}
parallel::stopCluster(cl = my.cluster)
params.all
```

The result is now:

```
         [,1] 
result.1 "foo"
result.2 "foo"
```

Isn't it weird or is it normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, and has nothing to do with parallel processing or `dopar`. The key is to ask yourself "what is each iteration of `dopar` actually outputting?"

To answer this, you need to realise that `print` invisibly returns the object it is printing:

```r
x <- 1:3
y <- print(x)
#> [1] 1 2 3

y
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

Whereas assignation with `<-` silently returns the assigned value:

```r
y <- (x <- "foo")

y
#> [1] "foo"
```

In your first version, with `print` uncommented, each `dopar` iteration is outputting `params` because the last call in the `dopar` loop is `print(params)`.

When you comment out the line `print(params)`, the last line of each iteration is `params$rmse <- "foo"`, so your iteration is not actually outputting `params`. It is returning the output of the assignation `params$rmse <- "foo"`, which is just the string `"foo"`. Therefore, you just get a single string `"foo"` for each iteration of `dopar`.

We can see this is standard behaviour using only base R:

```r
params.all <- do.call('rbind',
  lapply(1:3, function(i) {
      params <- iris[i,]
      params$Species <- 'foo'
      print(params)
}))

params.all
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     foo
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     foo
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     foo
```

Versus

```r
params.all <- do.call('rbind',
  lapply(1:3, function(i) {
      params <- iris[i,]
      params$Species <- 'foo'
      #print(params)
}))

params.all
#>      [,1] 
#> [1,] "foo"
#> [2,] "foo"
#> [3,] "foo"
```

The solution is to ensure that you specifically return the object at the end of the `dopar` loop. You can just make the last line `params` rather than `print(params)`.

In other words, your question could be rewritten as "`foreach` gives the expected output only if I return the correct object from the loop"

Comment: wow, thanks for the clarification! This is really the first time I noticed this and it is good to know it now (especially knowing it is expected behavior even in lapply which I have been using extensively...). Probably the tricky part to understand (for me at least) is that there is no explicit `return` statement, but indeed it means the last thing in the foreach is the returned value. Thanks again!