# Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection on Unix

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I have tried running the following code on a Unix machine with 20 CPU, using R `foreach`, `parallel`, `doParallel`, and `party` packages (my objective is to have the party / varimp function working on several CPUs in parallel):

```
parallel_compute_varimp <- function (object, mincriterion = 0, conditional = FALSE, threshold = 0.2, 
    nperm = 1, OOB = TRUE, pre1.0_0 = conditional) 
{
    response <- object@responses
    input <- object@data@get("input")
    xnames <- colnames(input)
    inp <- initVariableFrame(input, trafo = NULL)
    y <- object@responses@variables[[1]]
    error <- function(x, oob) mean((levels(y)[sapply(x, which.max)] != y)[oob])

    w <- object@initweights
    perror <- matrix(0, nrow = nperm * length(object@ensemble), ncol = length(xnames))
    colnames(perror) <- xnames

    data = foreach(b = 1:length(object@ensemble), .packages = c("party","stats"), .combine = rbind) %dopar%
    {
        try({
            tree <- object@ensemble[[b]]
            oob <- object@weights[[b]] == 0

            p <- .Call("R_predict", tree, inp, mincriterion, -1L, PACKAGE = "party")

            eoob <- error(p, oob)

            for (j in unique(varIDs(tree))) {
                for (per in 1:nperm) {
                    if (conditional || pre1.0_0) {
                      tmp <- inp
                      ccl <- create_cond_list(conditional, threshold, xnames[j], input)
                      if (is.null(ccl)) {
                        perm <- sample(which(oob))
                      }
                      else {
                        perm <- conditional_perm(ccl, xnames, input, tree, oob)
                      }
                      tmp@variables[[j]][which(oob)] <- tmp@variables[[j]][perm]
                      p <- .Call("R_predict", tree, tmp, mincriterion, -1L, PACKAGE = "party")
                    }
                    else {
                      p <- .Call("R_predict", tree, inp, mincriterion, as.integer(j), PACKAGE = "party")
                    }
                    perror[b, j] <- (error(p, oob) - eoob)
                }
            }

            ########
            # return data to the %dopar% loop data variable
            perror[b, ]
            ########

        }) # END OF TRY
    } # END OF LOOP WITH PARALLEL COMPUTING

    perror = data
    perror <- as.data.frame(perror)
    return(MeanDecreaseAccuracy = colMeans(perror))
}

environment(parallel_compute_varimp) <- asNamespace('party')


cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl, cores = detectCores())
<...>
system.time(data.cforest.varimp <- parallel_compute_varimp(data.cforest, conditional = TRUE))
```

but I am getting an error:

```
> system.time(data.cforest.varimp <- parallel_compute_varimp(data.cforest, conditional = TRUE))
Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection
Timing stopped at: 58.302 13.197 709.307
```

The code was working with a smaller dataset on 4 CPUs.

I am running out of ideas. Can someone suggest a way to reach my objective of running party package varimp function on parallel CPUs?

Comment: did you figure out this issue?

Comment: I don't think so. I forgot all about it anyway :)

Answer (score 44):

The error:

```
Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection
```

means that the master process got an error when calling unserialize to read from the socket connection to one of the workers. That probably means that the corresponding worker died, thus dropping its end of the socket connection. Unfortunately, it may have died for any number of reasons, many of which are very system specific.

You can usually figure out why the worker died by using the makeCluster "outfile" option so that the error message generated by the worker isn't thrown away. I usually recommend using `outfile=""` as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15078540/2109128). Note that the "outfile" option works the same in both the snow and parallel packages.

You could also verify that your foreach loop works correctly when executed sequentially by registering the sequential backend:

```
registerDoSEQ()
```

If you're lucky, the foreach loop will fail when executed sequentially, since it's usually easier to figure out what is going wrong.