# do parallel combine progress bar and process

Tags: r, function, parallel-processing, progress-bar

I'm having issues to combine the process that I want to run in parallel and the creation of the progress bar.

My code for the process is:

```
pred_pnn <- function(x, nn){
  xlst <- split(x, 1:nrow(x))
  pred <- foreach(i = xlst,.packages = c('tcltk', 'foreach'), .combine = rbind) 
  %dopar% 
{ mypb <- tkProgressBar(title = "R progress bar", label = "",
                        min = 0, max = max(jSeq), initial = 0, width = 300)
  foreach(j = jSeq) %do% {Sys.sleep(.1)
  setTkProgressBar(mypb, j, title = "pb", label = NULL)
  }  
  library(pnn)
 data.frame(prob = guess(nn, as.matrix(i))$probabilities[1], row.names = NULL)
}
}
```

I combined my code and the one that comes form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903787/how-can-i-print-when-using-dopar)

but didn't compile. I get a syntax error, but I can't find it.

I tried this other code:

```
pred_pnn <- function(x, nn){
  xlst <- split(x, 1:nrow(x))
  pred <- foreach(i = xlst, .combine = rbind) %dopar% 
{library(pnn)
 cat(i, '\n')
 data.frame(prob = guess(nn, as.matrix(i))$probabilities[1], row.names = NULL)
}
}
```

But I get an error too.

Answer (score 5):

The approach that you're trying to use might work under certain circumstances, but it isn't a good general solution. What I would want to do is to create a progress bar in the master process (outside of the `foreach` loop) and then have `foreach` update that progress bar as tasks are returned. Unfortunately, none of the backends support that. It's possible to do that using combine function tricks, but only if you're using a backend that supports calling the combine function on-the-fly, which `doParallel`, `doSNOW` and `doMC` do not. Those backends don't call combine on the fly because they are implemented using functions such as `clusterApplyLB` and `mclapply` which don't support a hook to allow user supplied code to be executed when tasks are returned.

Because I've seen interest in progress bar support in `foreach`, I modified the `doSNOW` package to add support for a doSNOW-specific "progress" option, and I checked the code into the R-Forge website. It makes use of some lower level functions in the `snow` package which unfortunately are not exported by the `parallel` package.

If you want to try out this new feature, you will need to install `doSNOW` from R-Forge. I did this on my MacBook Pro using the command:

```
install.packages("doSNOW", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type="source")
```

Here is a simple example script that demonstrates the experimental "progess" option:

```
library(doSNOW)
library(tcltk)
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(3)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
pb <- tkProgressBar(max=100)
progress <- function(n) setTkProgressBar(pb, n)
opts <- list(progress=progress)
r <- foreach(i=1:100, .options.snow=opts) %dopar% {
  Sys.sleep(1)
  sqrt(i)
}
```

*Update*

The `progress` option is now available in the latest version of doSNOW on CRAN.