# How to handle API error in a foreach loop R?

Tags: r, foreach, error-handling, parallel-processing

FYI, based on some comments I added more information.

I created the following function that is making a call to an API:

```
keyword_checker <- function(keyword, domain, loc, lang){

  keyword_to_check <- as.character(keyword)

  api_request <- paste("https://script.google.com/blabalbalba",
                       "?kw=",keyword,
                       "&domain=",domain,
                       "&loc=",loc,
                       "&lang=",lang,sep="")
  api_request <- URLencode(api_request, repeated = TRUE)  
  source <-fromJSON(file = api_request)#Json file into Data Frame
  return(data.frame(do.call("rbind", source$data$result))) ##in order to extract only the "results" data
```

I am using the R package `foreach()` with `%dopar%` and `doSNOW` to do many API calls (more than 120k calls). 
Unfortunately, it happens that there are some `errors` (usually time out connection), so it makes the script stops. In order to avoid this problem I used the `.errorhandling = 'pass'`. Now, the script doesn't stop but I would like to know if there is a way to make the API call until I get an answer?

Here is my script:

```
cl <- makeCluster(9)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

final_urls_checker <- foreach(i = 1:length(mes_urls_to_check), .combine=rbind, .errorhandling = 'pass', .packages='rjson') %dopar% {
  test_keyword <- as.character(mes_urls_to_check[i])
  results <- indexed_url(test_keyword)}  ##name of my function

##Stop cluster
stopCluster(cl)
```

I basically want my script to continue (without stopping the whole process) until I get the answer from the API call

Do I need to incorporate the `TryCatch` function within the `foreach`, OR is that better to "upgrade" the function that I created by adding something like "if the API doesn't give the answer, then wait until it gets it?"

I hope this is clearer.

Comment: May be by adding `try catch` block inside `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `tryCatch` inside the `foreach` function to catch the expected error messages (here failed API call due to time out). Below is a sample code snippet for the given function `keyword_checker`, based on my understanding.

```
library(foreach)
 cl <- makeCluster(9)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

final_urls_checker <- foreach(i = 1:length(mes_urls_to_check), .combine=rbind, .errorhandling = 'pass', 
    .packages='rjson') %dopar% {
  test_keyword <- as.character(mes_urls_to_check[i])
  #results <- keyword_checker(test_keyword)}  ##name of my function
  results <- function(test_keyword){
    dmy <- tryCatch(
    {
        keyword_checker(test_keyword)
    },
    error = function(cond){
        message = "Timeout error! Calling again..."
        dmy2 <- keyword_checker(test_keyword)
        return(dmy2) 
    }
    warning = function(cond){
        message("Warning message:")
        message(cond)
        return(NULL)
    }
    finally = {
        message(paste("Succesfully called API ", test_keyword))
    }
        )
    return(dmy)
  }

##Stop cluster
stopCluster(cl)
```

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r) which explains how to write `tryCatch`. Note, this snippet may not exactly work since I didn't run the code block. But calling the API caller again, when it fails should do the job.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39262612/r-show-error-and-warning-messages-in-foreach-dopar), for a discussion on similar issue.

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried to give more information about my question.  hope this will be easier to understand

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'll try it asap. I'll also update my answer because I tried `trycatch` directly in the function I created and this is also working

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated script including the `TryCatch` directly in the function.

```
indexed_url <- function(url){

  url_to_check <- as.character(url)

  api_request <- paste("https://script.google.com/macros/blablabalbalbaexec",
                       "?page=",url_to_check,sep="")
  api_request <- URLencode(api_request, repeated = TRUE)  
  source <- tryCatch({
    fromJSON(file = api_request)#Convertir un Json file en Data Frame  
  }, error = function(e) {
    cat(paste0("Une erreur a eu lieu :",e))
    Sys.sleep(1)
    indexed_url(url)
  })  
  return(data.frame(do.call("rbind", source)))
}
```

Then running the `foreach` just the way it was is working perfectly. No more errors, and I have the full analysis.