# How to make R foreach threads write to same log file

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, logfile, sink

I have a number of lengthy jobs that I want to parallelize with foreach-dopar so that each thread works on a job independent of others. I want to track the status of each thread (some may fail while others succeed) by writing to a log file using `sink`. The following apparently doesn't work; the log file has only one entry.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(doSNOW)

cl = makeCluster(2, type="SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)
dl = file("runlog.Rout", open="wt")
sink(dl, type="output",  append=TRUE)
sink(dl, type="message", append=TRUE)
dump <- foreach(i=1:5, 
            .errorhandling = "stop",
            .verbose=TRUE) %dopar% 
{
    beg.time = Sys.time()
    cat(as.character(beg.time), " I am running....\n", file="mylog.txt")
    # do something here.....
    end.time = Sys.time()
    del.tm = difftime(end.time, beg.time, units="mins")  
    cat("....saving output to file......\n\n", file="mylog.txt")
    save(del.tm, file = paste("I:/Rhome/H", i, ".RData", sep=""))
    return(i)
}
stopCluster(cl)
sink(type="output")
sink(type="message")
```

The log file has just one line :

```
....saving output to file......
```

What went wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I don't really trust having multiple processes write to the same file, you may have success by using the `append=TRUE` option:

```
cat("...\n", file="mylog.txt", append=TRUE)
```

Without setting this option, `cat` will overwrite the previous contents of "mylog.txt" each time it's called.

For other approaches, see [my answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15078540/2109128)

Comment: That's exactly what's missing!

Comment: Could please elaborate on the issue of multiple processes writing to the same file? Do you think this could lead to unexpected outputs in the file or even a crash of the run?

Answer (score 2):

You can also call `makeCluster` with the argument `outfile`. From the documentatino, `outfile` is

> Where to direct the stdout and stderr connection output from the workers. "" indicates no redirection (which may only be useful for workers on the local machine). Defaults to ‘/dev/null’ (‘nul:’ on Windows). The other possibility is a file path on the worker's host. Files will be opened in append mode, as all workers log to the same file.