# Write to log file using doMPI

Tags: r, parallel-processing, openmpi, doparallel, dompi

I am running doMPI on an HPC and I would like to log output from workers. Using doParallel, I was able to use `makeCluster(outfile='myfile.log')`. With doMPI, there does not seem to be an `outfile` argument in any of the methods. I tried using `sinkWorkerOutput()`. This works, but only wrote the log for one of the workers. I suspect that each worker is overwriting the other. Is there an analog for `outfile` for doMPI?

A related question - inside of a worker, can I find the worker number?

EDIT: here is a link to an answer discussing how to use outfile: [How can I print when using %dopar%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903787/how-can-i-print-when-using-dopar)

Thank you for your help,

Ben

Comment: What about putting `sink` or `cat` inside your function?

Answer (score 0):

To send worker output to a file in the `doMPI` package, set the `startMPIcluster` "verbose" option to `TRUE`:

```
cl <- startMPIcluster(verbose=TRUE)
```

This creates one file per worker with names of the form "MPI_1_steve_41747.log". The MPI rank, user name, and process ID is used to make the file names unique. You can also specify the log directory via the "logdir" option.

To get a worker number, you can simply call the `mpi.comm.rank` function.