# doParallel seems to corrupts output for unknown reason

Tags: r, multithreading, parallel-processing, doparallel

I'm attempting to run the following code (used for EWAS purposes) in a parallel format:

```
registerDoParallel(2)

combined <- foreach(i = 28:78, .combine=rbind)  %dopar%                 
{
mm<-rep(NA,412) 

FIDunique<-unique(pheno$FID)
for(j in FIDunique)
{
  nn<-which(pheno1$FID==j)
  mm[nn]<-mean(pheno1[nn,i])
}
tt4<-which(!is.na(mm))

if(length(tt4)>19 & length(table(pheno1[,i]))>1)
{
  meth<-pheno1[tt4,i]
  mm<-mm[tt4]

  if(length(levels(factor(pheno1$smoking)))<2) 
  {
    lme2<-tryCatch(lme(I(meth-mm)~delta_residSpine+I(DNA_year-AGE_year)+CD8T+CD4T+NK+Bcell+Mono+Gran,random=~1|FID, control=lmeControl(msMaxIter=50000,opt="optim"), data=pheno1[tt4,]),error = function(e) rep (NaN,1)) 
  }
  else 
  {
    lme2<-tryCatch(lme(I(meth-mm)~delta_residSpine+I(DNA_year-AGE_year)+factor(smoking)+CD8T+CD4T+NK+Bcell+Mono+Gran,random=~1|FID, control=lmeControl(msMaxIter=50000,opt="optim"), data=pheno1[tt4,]),error = function(e) rep (NaN,1))
  }

  if(!is.na(lme2)) out18[i-27,2:5]<-summary(lme2)$tTable[2,-3]

  rm(mm,nn,meth,lme2)
}

out18[i-27,6]<-length(tt4)
out18[i-27,]
}
```

The issue i'm having is that when I use %do% in the second line, the program executes perfectly and 'combined' contains the [the correct output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf5GD.png)

However when I use %dopar% (as is shown in the code above), [the middle four columns of combined dissapear.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz16R.png) I suppose this is due to those four columns being assigned based on a tryCatch? I've been stuck on this for a few days and really need to make progress.

It's also worth nothing that when I run the program as a %do%, I get the warning

> Warning in if (!is.na(lme2)) out18[i - 27, 2:5] <- summary(lme2)$tTable[2,  :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

for every iteration, however I do not get this at all when running under %dopar%.

Apologies if I haven't given enough information on what the variables are, i'm trying to disclose as little as possible about the actual information being processed for ethical reasons.

Comment: it's not easy to follow your problem. What Os are you running on ? `%do%` and `%dopar%` definitely don't have the same behaviour, and `%dopar%` can depend on the Os.

Comment: Your problem comes probably from the fact that you try to update a value while using `foreach` (namely the `out18` array) which does not make sense. Try using a new vector instead and returning it only. The `.combine` options will cat the result correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right that an unexpected error is hidden by the tryCatch. For instance, since you're using the `lme` function, shouldn't you be loading the `nlme` package on your workers? As in:

```
r <- foreach(i = 28:78, .packages='nlme', .combine=rbind)  %dopar% {
  #snip
}
```

There might be other issues, such as objects that have to be explicitly exported, so I suggest that you change your code to not hide unexpected errors, especially while testing/debugging. A simple approach is to log the error and then return the appropriate value:

```
tryCatch(foo(), error = function(e) {
  print(e)
  NaN
})
```

In order to see these log messages, you could use the makeCluster `outfile=""` option so the messages will be displayed in your terminal. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15078540/2109128) for more information.

I also suggest that you change your test to something like:

```
if (!identical(lme2, NaN)) ...
```

This will avoid the warning when `lme2` isn't a `NaN` since `identical` never returns a value with length > 1.