# Unwanted result from parallel computation with forerach

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, foreach, doparallel

I want to print a message after every 5 iterations in a loop. This works in a base R loop as follows:

```
vec = c() # empty vector
for (i in 1:100) {
        
        s = sqrt(i)
        vec = c(vec, s)
        if (i %% 5 == 0) {
                print(paste0("Iteration number: ", i, " finished running"))
        }
        
}
```

I want to be able to do the same using paralel computation with `forerach`. So far I have done the following:

```
vec = c() # empty vector
library(doParallel); library(foreach)
ncores = detectCores() # number of cores in my computer
registerDoParallel(ncores)
foreach (i = 1:100) %dopar% {
        
        s = sqrt(i)
        vec = c(vec, s)
        if (i %% 5 == 0) {
                print(paste0("Iteration number: ", i, " finished running"))
        }
        
}
stopImplicitCluster()
```

However, it does not work the way I want. It also prints `NULL`s for some reason in a "list-like" format. How can I achieve the same result from the base R loop in the `forerach` approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the messages printed on each multiple of 5 are strictly not need, the following will create two identical vectors.
Note that I create `vec` beforehand and that I use `message` in the loop.

```
vec <- numeric(100)
for (i in 1:100) {
  vec[i] <- sqrt(i)
  if (i %% 5 == 0) {
    message(paste0("Iteration number: ", i, " finished running"))
  }
}

library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

ncores <- detectCores() # number of cores in my computer
registerDoParallel(ncores)

vec2 <- foreach(i = 1:100, .combine = c) %dopar% {
  sqrt(i)
}
stopImplicitCluster()

identical(vec, vec2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Your code works well. But I still want to be able to see the progress of the iterations (in reality I have to run thousands of iterations). Is there any other way that I could somehow track the progress in the `forerach` approach?

Comment: [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903787/how-can-i-print-when-using-dopar) has some ideas on how to track the progress in `%dopar%`