# Replace a for loop with foreach in r

Tags: r, loops, foreach

I want to replace the for loop with a foreach loop but I get an error "unexpected token in". Below you can see my code. Just to mention that all the f's are file names. Do you have any idea?

```
for (f in file) {
  print(f)
  analyze(f)
  tmp <- res4
  y <- rbind(y, tmp)
}
```

Comment: The example code is not reproducible, `file`, `y` and `res4` are missing. And so is function `analyze`. Can you give a simple yet reproducible example, say, with a dummy function `analyze<- function(x) {sum(x)}` or something like that, simple?

Comment: r doesn't have a foreach statement, are you using the foreach package?

Comment: Suppose file = c("/data/an_01h.dat", "/data/an_01h.dat"). How can I run a simple forech? for (f in file) {
  print(f)
}

Comment: Yes I use the foreach package

Comment: The error you received is a syntax error for the code you haven't shown us.  You should post code that reproduces the error you saw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple `foreach` loop  using the sequential `%do%` operator.
Note that the first 2 values of vector `file` are the output of `print`.

```r
library(foreach)

file <- c("/data/an_01h.dat", "/data/an_01h.dat")
foreach (f=file) %do% {
  print(f)
}
#> [1] "/data/an_01h.dat"
#> [1] "/data/an_01h.dat"
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "/data/an_01h.dat"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "/data/an_01h.dat"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

And a parallelized loop. The `%dopar%` operator is a parallelizable operator. This time `print` doesn't show its output, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903787/how-can-i-print-when-using-dopar) on this.

```r
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
#> Loading required package: iterators
#> Loading required package: parallel

file <- c("/data/an_01h.dat", "/data/an_01h.dat")

ncores <- detectCores() - 1L
registerDoParallel(ncores)  # use multicore, set to the number of our cores
foreach (f=file) %dopar% {
  print(f)
}
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "/data/an_01h.dat"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "/data/an_01h.dat"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>